# Batch script to edit a file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file having following contents -

```
SF:D:\Saurabh\Work\WS\devicehowto.war\scripts\.\Greeter.js
DA:1,2
DA:4,2
DA:5,2
end_of_record
SF:D:\Saurabh\Work\WS\devicehowto.war\scripts\.\GreeterTest.js
DA:1,2
DA:3,2
DA:4,2
end_of_record
```

I need a batch script to replace all occurrence of "D:\Saurabh\Work\WS\devicehowto.war\scripts.\" with space character. So, after running the batch script the content should look like -

```
SF:Greeter.js
    DA:1,2
    DA:4,2
    DA:5,2
    end_of_record
    SF:GreeterTest.js
    DA:1,2
    DA:3,2
    DA:4,2
    end_of_record
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: These answers might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (saurabh.txt) DO (
 SET "line=%%i"
 SET "line=!line:D:\Saurabh\Work\WS\devicehowto.war\scripts\.\=!"
 ECHO(!line!
)
)>new.txt
TYPE new.txt
GOTO :eof
```

producing new.txt.

Not sure why the second and successive lines are indented. If this is deliberate, please specify criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. This is working fine. Just one thing. Can we update same file instead of writing output in new.txt?

Comment: Not in-place. simply `move /y new.txt saurabh.txt` where the `type` is.

Answer (score 1):

good job for [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

```
sed "/SF/s/:.*\\/:/" saurabh.txt
```